# Detailed tutorial for Quickly and python for app development?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

Where can I get a complete reference for ubuntu app development using Quickly and python? I saw the video at http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ but that shows only how to use a text field and button.

Comment: First of all, I would suggest you to read the O'Reilly book 'Programming Python' by Mark Lutz. But if you want to start programming right now, you have to draw attention on articles in 'Full Circle Magazine'. You can find the first article in issue #27. Download it here --> http://dl.fullcirclemagazine.org/issue27_en.pdf

Answer (score 3):

For development using quickly i would recommend these documentation:

- [Pygtk 3 documentation - for understanding the glade objects](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)
- [Python 2.7 documentation - for the code](http://docs.python.org/2/)
- [For making a gui (explore this site a bit)](http://www.learningpython.com/2006/05/07/creating-a-gui-using-pygtk-and-glade/)